# htaccess redirect only query without string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect following URL as follows:

```
https://www.example.com/news/amp/?s
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/amp?s
```

**2nd URL has no "/" before ?s**

I tried using following code, but failed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^news/amp/?s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/amp?s   [R=301,L]
```

But its not working, can any one suggest correction for this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below we are using `%{THE_REQUEST}` for matching instead of `%{QUERY_STRING}` which match only query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/news/amp/?s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/amp?s [R=301,L]
```